# Finding the electric and magnetic fields from the vector potential $\vec A=\vec{E_0} e^{i(\vec k\cdot\vec r-\omega t)}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential, vector-fields

I am trying to find the electric and magnetic fields from the vector potential $$\vec A=\vec{E_0} e^{i(\vec k\cdot\vec  r-\omega t)},$$

I know $$\vec B=\vec \nabla\times \vec A$$ and $$\vec E=-\vec\nabla \phi-\frac1c\partial_t\vec A$$ but I am confused by how to look at the vectors $\vec k$ and $\vec r$ (what is the $\vec x$?) and by the lack of given $\phi$.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\vec{k} = k_x \hat{x} + k_y \hat{y} + k_z \hat{z}$, and $\vec{r} = x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z}$;  the coordinate dependence is encoded in the $\vec{r}$.  These expressions are in Cartesian components, but if you ever need to calculate this in curvlinear coordinates, the logic would be the same.
2. If $\phi$ is not specified, you can probably assume that it's zero.  Given the form of the $\vec{A}$ you have, I suspect this is the intent of whoever's asking the problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether these solutions seem correct?

$\vec B=(-k_y E_{0z}+k_z E_{0y} , k_x E_{0z}-k_z E_{0x}, -k_x E_{0y}+k_y E_{0x})\cdot sin(k_x x+k_y y+k_z z-\omega t)$

$\vec E=\frac1c \vec {E_0} sin(k_x x+k_y y+k_z z-\omega t)(k_x \dot x+k_y \dot y+ k_z \dot z - \omega)$

Comment: @Whyka: $x$, $y$, and $z$ are coordinates in space, not coordinates of some particle;  so $\partial x/ \partial t = 0$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$.  Otherwise, that looks right to me.

Comment: If $\phi$ is not specified then you can only constrain the time-dependent electric field.

Comment: @RobJeffries:  Can you elaborate on that?  I'm reading it to mean that you can determine $\partial \vec{E}/\partial t$ without knowing $\phi$, which I don't think is true (since $\phi$ can itself depend on $t$.)

Comment: I mean if you know $A$ then you can define $\phi$ using  (e.g.) the Lorenz gauge, but then the E-field is indeterminate by a time-independent vector field. In the example above $\nabla \cdot {\bf A} = 0$, so $\partial_t \phi=0$, so $\phi (r)$ is time-independent, as is $- \nabla \phi$. Although looking again, maybe I'm assuming it's an EM wave.